# Attribute "editable" of SVG <text> not working

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I want to make a svg text editable. After some research, I found that editable attribute can specifies whether the contents of svg elements can be edited in place (http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-SVG12-20041027/text.html).

So I tried:

```html
<text editable="true" x="0" y="20" font-size="18" font-family="Arial" fill="#000080">Name:</text>
```

However, I still could not edit it! (I used latest version of Google Chrome, Firefox and IE)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<text contenteditable="true" x="0" y="20" font-size="18" font-family="Arial" fill="#000080">Name:</text>
```

just replace editable with contentEditable :)

Comment: Replace editable by contentEditable only works with IE (contenteditable not works, typo?).

Comment: Works in other arrangement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49341091/3559690